# Data Visualization with hundreds of AWS billing Data CSV files when the header values change over time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

I am developing a Data Visualization Dashboard in Tableau with hundreds of CSV files in the AWS S3 bucket and every day new files will be generated. 
In order to achieve this and make the process faster, I am loading the files into AWS Redshift DB. The CSV file has new columns and sometimes previously existing columns will not be present in the incoming files. In order to handle this I have modified my code to read and compare the headers, if new headers are present it will alter table, add new columns.

However the issue I am facing is the following:

1. CSV file header values change over time, i.e If the current value of a column is `'cost'`, in the next month the `'cost'` column might not be present but it's mapped to a new column by value `'Blended Cost'`.
2. The copy command to Redshift only works when the header positions match the column positions in the table. However with such a dynamic file, matching column positions is not feasible. I'm exploring Dynamo DB option to overcome this issue.

What would be the best way to handle this situation? Any recommendation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Gee, I guess managing metadata is important after all. Are you sure that Amazon does not provide anything to keep track of the fields and their meaning?

Comment: Slightly improved formatting